# Underscore.js - get unique property values

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, lodash

I only recently discovered the power of underscore.js, still new to the methods I kindly ask for a suggestion:

How do I get from this:

```
[
    [{
        "name": "Type 2",
        "id": 14
    }],
    [{
        "name": "Type 1",
        "id": 13
    }, {
        "name": "Type 3",
        "id": 15
    }],
    [{
        "name": "Type 2",
        "id": 14
    }],
    [{
        "name": "Type 1",
        "id": 13
    }]
]
```

to this:

```
["Type 1","Type 2","Type 3"]
```

i.e. no duplicated and "name" property only.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try anything? That should be straightforward.

Comment: @BlackSheep - I was able to do this in couple of steps. But I was missing the `flatten` method which makes the chaining possible.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
_(data).chain().flatten().pluck('name').unique().value()
```

(Convert the nested lists to a flat one, pick `name` from each of the objects in the list, and make it unique.)

Comment: Is there any particular merit to chaining methods in underscore/lo-dash compared to nesting (as in McGarnagle's answer). Or is it purely for aesthetics/code clarity?

Comment: In lodash it is more efficient if you create a wrapper with `_()` if you chain multiple methods together, less efficient if you only do one (maybe two) operations. Do your own benchmarks for each situation.

Answer (score 10):

- Use [`flatten`](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten) first, to convert the nested array to a flat array.
- Then [`pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) to get the "name" values as an array
- Finally [`uniq`](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq)

---

```
_.uniq(_.pluck(_.flatten(items), "name"))
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZr7L/2/)

Answer (score 3):

```
_.uniq(_.pluck(x,'name'));
```

the above code is sufficient for extracting different "name" attribute

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = _.uniq(_.map(_.flatten(array), function(e) {
    return e.name;
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

1. use _.map to get all the names

```
var names = _.map(items, function(item) { return item.name});
```

2. Get the _.uniq from that names

```
var uniqueNames = _.uniq(names);
```